# Sympy solve returns `NoneType object not scriptable`

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have tested this with both `sympy==1.7.1` and `sympy==1.5.1` and get the same result.

```
from sympy import *
import inspect

THT,HT,DBH,dib, c0,c1, c2,c3,c4  = symbols('THT HT DBH dib c0 c1 c2 c3 c4')
init_printing()

f = c2 + (c3*DBH) + (c4 * THT)
rhs = 1 - (((HT-1)/(THT - 1))**c1)* (1- exp(c0/f))

eqn = solve( dib - (DBH * (c0 - (f * ln(rhs)))), HT)
```

Which returns

```
# Out [37]: 
# output

TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-619e8281e2ae> in <module>
      9 # original rhs = 1 - (((HT-1)/(THT - 1))**c1)* (1- exp(c0/f))
     10 
---> 11 eqn = solve( dib - (DBH * (c0 - (f * ln(rhs)))), HT)
     12 
     13 #eqn = solve( dib - (DBH * (b1+b2 * ln(1-(lam*p)))), HT)

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py in solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
   1095         ok = False
   1096         if fi.has(*symset):
-> 1097             ok = True
   1098         else:
   1099             if fi.is_number:

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py in _solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
   1458         result = list(result)
   1459         if check:
-> 1460             # all solutions have been checked but now we must
   1461             # check that the solutions do not set denominators
   1462             # in any factor to zero

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
:end:
```

I can solve the following paired-down version:

```
In [47]: solve( f * ln(rhs), HT)
Out[47]: 
⎡c1___       c1___    ⎤
⎣╲╱ 0 ⋅THT - ╲╱ 0  + 1⎦
```

and adding an integer in place of `c0` it will solve:

```
solve( 2-(f * ln(rhs)), HT)
```

[image]

But adding a symbol causes the `NoneType` error. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a bug I think. Best to report it at github

Comment: Done, thanks!

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/20747